# How to read Query Parameters key and value

Tags: java, jpa

javax.persistence.Query

```
Query query = ....
query.setParameter("PARAM_1","1")
.setParameter("PARAM_2","2")
.setParameter("PARAM_3","3")
...
...;
```

I want to get parameters and write Console. Like this;

System out ;

```
PARAM_1 - 1
PARAM_2 - 2
PARAM_3 - 3
...
...
```

Comment: Have you tried with `query.getParameters()` java docs says [Query.html#getParameters()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getParameters())

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
java.util.Set<Parameter<?>> params = query.getParameters();
for (Parameter p : params) {
    String paramName = p.getName();
    System.out.print(paramName + " - ");
    System.out.println(query.getParameterValue(paramName));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just had to look at the javadoc, the method getParameters()

```
Query q = ...;
...
Set<Parameter<?>> parameters = q.getParameters();
for (Parameter<?> param : parameters){
    if (null == param.getName()){
        System.out.print(param.getPosition());
    } else {
        System.out.print(param.getName());
    }
    System.out.println(" - ");
    System.out.println(q.getParameterValue(param));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Query query = ...;
String[] keys = new String[] {"PARAM_1", "PARAM_2", "PARAM_3"};

for(String key : keys) {
   System.out.println(key + " - " + query.getParamValue(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check query interface. It has many methods like getParameter*(). See which one suits you.

Answer (score 0):

getParameter() helps you to understand more. Please [click](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getParameters()) here for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
((NativeQueryImpl) fQuery).getNamedParameterMap()
```